# Where do I get the archive of the Sons of Kryos podcast episodes?

Tags: podcast

So, I've heard a lot of English RPG podcasts and it turns out, that a lot of them constantly talk about the Sons of Kryos show. I thought this might be a good inspiration and went out to get hold of their episodes.

Turns out, their site at http://www.sonsofkryos.com/ is down. They have a LJ site at http://sonsofkryos.livejournal.com/, but all the audio files link to the aforementioned domain, which is unavailable. The same thing goes for their feedburner feed at http://feeds.feedburner.com/Sonsofkryos and a vast list of postcast aggregation sites like iTunes, podcasters.tv and others.

I tried looking on Isohunt, but no luck there. I also found a thread on Story Games on this (http://story-games.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=14170), but it seems like no-one uploaded anything.

So my question is: Where do I get the archive of the Sons of Kryos podcast episodes?

Thanks for your help. I guess you could help a lot of people with this.

Answer (score 6):

Episodes are being reposted here.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvQId2djk5AKlmoUIEkdDZQ

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you're affiliated with the Sons of Kryos podcast in some way (your username suggests it) we ask that you identify yourself as such in any posts about the podcast and (optionally) in your profile.

Answer (score 6):

The episodes are on archive.org at [https://archive.org/details/SonsOfKryosPodcast](https://archive.org/details/SonsOfKryosPodcast/)/

Answer (score 3):

[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) has a [video Sons of Kryos 1](http://vimeo.com/2804518).  I messaged the account there with a link to this thread.  Maybe someone who could/would help will see it :)